# Run artifact (.jar) in Eclipse after Maven build success

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk, jar, maven

I'm working on a Maven project, and after resolving many configuration problems, finally I am able to build the project successfully in Eclipse. After selecting `maven install` and seeing `build success`, a `.jar` artifact is now created in the `target` folder.

OK. Now as for the execution, instead of manually running the `.jar` in command line (`java -jar myJarFile.jar`), how can I automatically run it inside Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `exec-maven-plugin` the run the java launcher with the `jar` argument during the `integration-test` phase:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-jar</argument>
            <argument>target/myJar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>integration-test</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In Eclipse, right click, select `Run As` and choose `Maven Test` to run it.

**References**

- [java - Maven running jetty on integration-test stage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127982/maven-running-jetty-on-integration-test-stage)
- [java - Is there a good way to use maven to run an executable jar? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148044/is-there-a-good-way-to-use-maven-to-run-an-executable-jar)
- [Integration Testing with HTTP, HTTPS and Maven | ArchConf](https://archconf.com/blog/matt_raible/2011/02/integration_testing_with_http_https_and_maven)
- [Exec Maven Plugin – Running Java programs with the exec goal](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html)
- [3 ways to run Java main from Maven | Vineet Manohar's blog](http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/)
- [Integration Testing for Java EE](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/integrationtesting-487452.html)